# Use variable inside Hugo content

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I'm trying to use a variable within the content of a Hugo statically generated site. For example, the content looks like the following:

1. Go to your site's url (`{{ .Site.BaseURL }}`)
2. Enter your credentials
3. .....(blah blah blah)

When this gets rendered, the `{{ .... }}` part doesn't get processed...it stays the same as I put above. I've tried it with a `$` in front as well. Variables within templates seem to work just fine. Do I need to create a shortcode to use within content pages?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So it looks like a shortcode is the way to do this. For what it's worth, I changed the document to look like the following:

1. Go to your site's url ({{< siteurl >}})

In `layouts/shortcodes`, I created the file `siteurl.html`. It looks like the following:

```
{{ .Page.Site.BaseURL }}
```

I needed to add .Page in there to get access to the Site variables. See this [Issue Report](https://github.com/spf13/hugo/issues/442) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

In Hugo, When you want to use a variable in markdown *(.md)* file then you need to create a shortcode for that first.

You can follow these steps:-

#### create shortcode

*layouts/shortcodes/siteurl.html*

```
{{ .Page.Site.BaseURL }}
```

#### usage

*content/post/myblogpost.md*

```
---
# front-matter
---
1. Go to your site's url ({{< siteurl >}})
2. Enter your credentials
3. .....(blah blah blah)
```

#### result

*post/myblogpost.html*

```
1. Go to your site's url (https://codingnconcepts.com)
2. Enter your credentials
3. .....(blah blah blah)
```

**Source:** https://codingnconcepts.com/hugo/custom-shortcode-hugo/

Answer (score 3):

This is an attempt to slightly improve @minitauros answer with a simplistic example to lookup a (site) parameter sub-key (aka walk the YAML tree, infer an element, etc.).

I would like Hugo to have a JSONPath or jq syntax and, obviously, this example is far from competing with either solutions.

### `config.yml`

```yaml
params:
  mode: one
  support:
    mailing: info@example.net
```

### `layouts/shortcodes/param.html`

```golang
{{ $v := .Site.Params }}
{{ range (split (.Get 0) ".") }}{{ $v = index $v (.) }}{{ end }}
{{ $v }}
```

### `content/_index.md`

```markdown
We are in mode {{< param "mode" >}}.

In case of turbulence, [reach the support](mailto:{{< param "support.mailing" >}}) for help.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and this post helped me.

I wanted to display a site param in my site content, and discovered you cannot use regular templating inside content files.

In the end I created a shortcode to load the requested site param. Who knows this information might help someone.

/config.yml

```
params:
  appName: My app
```

/content/about.html

```
<p>My app's name is {{< param "appName" >}}</p>
```

/layouts/shortcodes/param.html

```
{{/* Usage: {{< param "siteParamName" }} */}}
{{ index .Site.Params (.Get 0) }}
```

Result

```
<p>My app's name is My app</p>
```